# How to create a roll-over effect for two divs at once in CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm working on a website - being very new to html and css, and I have a problem. You'll find my work in progress here: http://users.telenet.be/blijvendvertrek/default.htm.

Now I want to add an effect: when I hover over a navigation tab ('Renovaties', 'Gerechtelijke expertise bouw' or 'Over mij'), I want to see the hover effect of that tab AND at the same time the hover effect of the div below it (respectively the one with the constuction hat, the tie and the name) - and vice versa.

eg: hover over the 'Renovaties' tab, and the site will show the hover effect of that tab AND of the div below it - and vice versa.

I've been searching for solutions for five hours now, and that's why I reckoned I was allowed to ask it here ;-)

Thanks a million!

Davy

Answer (score 0):

Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UF3pu/

You wrap the heading/link and contents into a parent element, and then style the element so that when you hover over the parent, you change the styles of the children elements.

Like so:

```
section.services:hover h1, section.services:hover p {background: red;}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Not at the moment, but if he wants to be able to have this sort of functionality with CSS, he will need to change his mark up. Or he wouldn't be able to do it with CSS.

Comment: Dear Aaron, I'm very sorry, but I can't apply your solution because the headers are located in the <div id="navigation"> while the content for each header is located in the <div id="content">. That makes it impossible to 'wrap' them... Anyway: thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: Check out jQuery's ToggleClass: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ -- you could toggle classes on both elements which had the background color applied.

Comment: Dear Scott, can you please tell me how I would go about toggling classes in Dreamweaver? Thanks a million!